# How to reset inet(dsl) connection via console in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, console, windows-xp, ip, inet

all question in the title. All I want is to refresh ip only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ipconfig /renew`. You can also specify a the interface by name. See `ipconfig /?`

Comment: @StasonixNiculin: Maybe [this](http://chinmaykamat.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/script-to-restart-adsl-modem-automatically/) can guide you to a solution, even though it is not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`ipconfig /renew` will request a new DHCP lease.

However, this will not reset your WAN (External) IP Address, only the internal IP Address.